# Gluonnlp installation not found on Sagemaker jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, gluon

[image]I am attempting to install Gluonnlp to a sagemaker jupyter notebook. Im using the command `!sudo pip3 install gluonnlp` to install.  Which is successful.  However on import I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gluonnlp'`

I got the same issue when attempting to install mxnet with pip in the same notebook.  It was resolved when I conda installed mxnet instead.  However conda install has not been working for gluonnlp as it cannot find the package.  I can't seem to find a way to conda install gluonnlp.  Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Here are some of the commands I have tried

`!sudo pip3 install gluonnlp`

`!conda install gluonnlp` --> Anaconda cant find the package in any channels

```
!conda install pip --y
!sudo pip3 install gluonnlp

!sudo pip3 install gluonnlp

!conda install -c conda-forge gluonnlp --y
```

All these commands on my import 
import warnings

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import io
import random
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx
import gluonnlp as nlp
from bert import data, model
```

result in the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gluonnlp'
```

Comment: try : sudo -H pip3 install gluonnlp  , "-H" give permission to all users to use module

Comment: I just tried still doesn't recognize it.  I have had this happen before in sagemaker notebooks and the only solution I have come to is using anaconda but the package is not there.  I'm wondering if I can install with pip and then somehow have the anaconda recognize it

Comment: try : "conda install -c conda-forge gluonnip" this will install it in anaconda   for more read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-add-packages-to-anaconda-environment/

Comment: I'm getting really weird issues where it still is not recognizing it

Comment: edit this post and plz explain in detail, it's a large community someone will help you but first ask clearly if you can plz share screenshot or copy-paste error

Comment: I will but there really isn't much to share.  It just has the import just doesn't recognize the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is as simple as creating a Jupyter notebook using the 'conda_mxnet_p36' kernel, and adding a cell containing:

```
!pip install gluonnlp
```

Comment: I used the correct kernel like you stated and installed as you said but it still didn't work.  I did have to use a sudo on my install though if that effects anything

Comment: You shouldn't have to use 'sudo', unless you interfered with the conda setup.. Launch a new notebook instance and try again :)

Comment: OK will do, thanks for helping me work through this

Comment: That worked!  Any insight into what could have caused the notebook to initially be messed up.  Because it was not letting me install without sudo before.

Comment: One of those weird 'sudo' / 'conda' commands above? ;) The safe practice for notebook instance customization is either to 'pip install' in the notebook itself, or to use lifecycle configuration if you want to automate the process, create new conda environments, etc (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-your-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instances-with-lifecycle-configurations-and-the-option-to-disable-internet-access).